# Apply condition for pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

for instance:
I have a dataframe with 2 column and i want to add the 4th column on condition.

```
1stcolumn  2ndcolumn 
abc.       aaa-eee
abc.       abc-def
abc.       ccc-eee
abc.       c-ee-f-g
abc.       a
abc.       eee-eee
abc.       bbb-ddd
```

Condition is:
if the value in the 3rd column is like `[any value in a_list]-[any value in b_list]` , then the value in the column 4 should be `controlled" else "not controlled`

```
a_list = ['aaa','bbb','ccc'] 
b_list = ['ddd','eee']
```

expected output:

```
1stcolumn  2ndcolumn.   3rdcolumn 
abc.       aaa-eee.     controlled
abc.       abc-def.     not controlled
abc.       ccc-eee.     controlled
abc.       c-ee-f-g.    not controlled
abc.       a.           not controlled
abc.       eee-eee.     not controlled
abc.       bbb-ddd.     controlled
```

Comment: if the value is "aaa-eee" then result should be "controlled"
if the value is "abc-def" then result should be "not controlled"
if the value is "c-ee-f-g" then result should be "not controlled"
if the value is "eee-eee" then result should be "not controlled"
if the value is "bbb-ddd" then result should be "controlled"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create all combinations of values by [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), test column by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and set new values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
from  itertools import product

a_list = ['aaa','bbb','ccc'] 
b_list = ['ddd','eee']
new = [f'{a}-{b}' for a, b in product(a_list, b_list)]
print (new)
['aaa-ddd', 'aaa-eee', 'bbb-ddd', 'bbb-eee', 'ccc-ddd', 'ccc-eee']

df['3rdcolumn'] = np.where(df['2ndcolumn'].isin(new),'controlled','not controlled')
print (df)
  1stcolumn 2ndcolumn      3rdcolumn 
0      abc.   aaa-eee      controlled
1      abc.   abc-def  not controlled
2      abc.   ccc-eee      controlled
3      abc.  c-ee-f-g  not controlled
4      abc.         a  not controlled
5      abc.   eee-eee  not controlled
6      abc.   bbb-ddd      controlled
```

Comment: @kanna what is your python version?

Comment: @kanna if not working change `new = [f'{a}-{b}' for a, b in product(a_list, b_list)]`  to `new = ['{}-{}'. format(a, b) for a, b in product(a_list, b_list)]`